# could not connect to action "Button" in cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I am new in cocoa application development. I am trying to create model based application in cocoa.

I created two windows in cocoa application say mainMenu.xib and windows2.xib. The mainMenu.xib is created while project creation and windows2.xib is manually created. Now I inserted a button on mainMenu.xib say (button1) and when clicked on button then window2.xib poped up but **when click on button of second windows it is generated a error**. the code is follwoing

AppDelegate.h

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
```

And AppDelegate.mm

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate
  NSWindowController *AdvSettingController;
    - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
    {

// Insert code here to initialize your application
}

- (IBAction)AdvSettingBtn:(id)sender {

AdvSettingController= [[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"window2"];

[NSApp runModalForWindow:AdvSettingController.window];
[NSApp endSheet:AdvSettingController.window];
[AdvSettingController.window orderOut:self];
}

- (IBAction)OkBtn:(id)sender {
 [NSApp terminate:self];
}

- (IBAction)CancelBtn:(id)sender {
    [NSApp terminate:self];
    }
```

Now, windows2.h file for second windows(windows2.xib)

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface windows2 : NSWindowController
@end
```

and windows2.mm

```
#import "windows2.h"

@interface windows2 ()

@end

@implementation windows2

 - (id)initWithWindow:(NSWindow *)window
{


self = [super initWithWindowNibName:@"windows2"];
if (self) {     
// Initialization code here.


 }

return self;

}

- (void)windowDidLoad
{
    [super windowDidLoad];

    // Implement this method to handle any initialization after your window controller's window has been loaded from 
}
- (IBAction)CancelBtn:(id)sender { 
   [self.window close];
} **//Error is generating at run time when clicked on button of second dialog**
```

Comment: can you post the error log?

Comment: 2015-06-02 12:13:08.988 DeviceSetting[1166:38054] Could not connect the action CancelButton: to target of class NSWindowController

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to connect the `CancelButton` method, but the instance method is named `CancelBtn`.

Comment: Thank you !!! 
Actual problem was in file owner. I have changed the file owner from NSWindowsController to "CustomClass" (The class drive from NSWindowController.). :)